# Dynamic popover/tooltip via Bootstrap with flask & python

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create dynamically generated tooltip/popover content for a site using bootstrap (3.1), flask and python.

I have hyper-linked items in a table. When I mouse over those hyperlinks, I want a tooltip to appear; when the user clicks on the hyperlink I want them to go to the individual item page. Code (shortened for brevity):

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Color</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{% include 'itemlink.html' %}</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>red</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

then in itemlink.html:

```
 <a href="{{linkitem.get_url()}}" class="itemlink" data-item-id="{{linkitem.id}}">
   <img src="{{linkitem.image}}" alt="Item {{linkitem.id}}" class="smallicon" />
     {{linkitem|safe}}
 </a>
```

Next: the content of what I want to be in the popover/tooltip box:

```
<div id="item_{{boxitem.id}}" class="itembox">
    <div class="itemimage">
      <img src="{{boxitem.image}}" alt="{{boxitem.name}}" title="{{boxitem.get_title()}}" />
   </div>
   <div class="iteminfo">
     <div class="itemtitle">
       {{boxitem.get_title()}}
     </div>
     <div class="itemdesc">
        {% autoescape off %}{{boxitem.get_desc()}}{% endautoescape %}
      </div>
     </div>  
    </div>
```

I put this in a script on my page:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#item_{{item.id}}').popover({
     html: true,
     placement: 'right',
     trigger: 'hover',
     selector: '[rel="popover"]'
   });
  });
 </script>
```

I'm wondering if this part of the script is even possible?

```
  $('#item_{{item.id}}').popover({
```

EDIT TO ADD: (it's not, it threw a server error)
EDIT again: It had to be

```
$('.itembox#item_'+$(this).data(itemID')).popover
```

On what element should I add the rel=popover?

Comment: What server error did it throw? Can you show the flask server trace?

Answer (score 0):

I would give each item a static class like tool tip or give the table an id and use jQuery selector on the element in the table for the hover event. 
  `$(document).ready(function(){
   $('td.tooltip').popover({
     html: true,
     placement: 'right',
     trigger: 'hover',
     selector: '[rel="popover"]'
   });
  })`;

Comment: I tried this one- but then when I hover over any single element, it shows all of the popup boxes. I think it's on the right track though. ^_^